# Python re establishment after Server shuts down

Tags: python

I have a python script running on my server which accessed a database, executes a fetch query and runs a learning algorithm to classify and updates certain values and means depending on the query.

I want to know if for some reason my server shuts down in between then my python script would shut down and my query lost.

How do i get to know where to continue from once I re-run the script and i want to carry on the updated means from the previous queries that have happened.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: the question is not really related to Python at all. It's a general problem.

And the answer is simple: keep track of what your script does (in a file or directly in db). If it crashes continue from the last step.